# PHP: preg_replace() - need to replace a textNode string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following problem and I am not really good in regular expressions, so please, could somebody help me out?

```
<div class="bulletPoints">
    <div>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId0" title="test_f01"><img src="../images/test_f01.jpg" alt="test_f01"/>1</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId1" title="test_f02"><img src="../images/test_f02.jpg" alt="test_f02"/>2</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId2" title="test_f03"><img src="../images/test_f03.jpg" alt="test_f03"/>3</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId3" title="test_f04"><img src="../images/test_f04.jpg" alt="test_f04"/>4</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId4" title="test_f05"><img src="../images/test_f05.jpg" alt="test_f05"/>5</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId5" title="test_f06"><img src="../images/test_f06.jpg" alt="test_f06"/>6</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId6" title="test_f07"><img src="../images/test_f07.jpg" alt="test_f07"/>7</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId7" title="test_f08"><img src="../images/test_f08.jpg" alt="test_f08"/>8</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId8" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/>9</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId9" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/>10</a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId10" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/>11</a>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to replace the plain text string after the image tag inside of each anchor tag. The string is always a number from 0 - 99. The IDs of the anchor tags are auto generated and the title attribute, too. I don't know how to reach only the number on all tags. I need to replace it with an empty string `''`. Could somebody help me and explain how I can do that??

Thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>)(\d+)/', "\\1", $text);
```

This will replace the image tag + text after the image tag with only the image tag.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `/>[0-9]{,2}<` with `/><`

test with sed:

```
echo 'yourtext'|sed -r 's#/>[0-9]{,2}<#/><#g'
```

output:

```
<div class="bulletPoints">
    <div>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId0" title="test_f01"><img src="../images/test_f01.jpg" alt="test_f01"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId1" title="test_f02"><img src="../images/test_f02.jpg" alt="test_f02"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId2" title="test_f03"><img src="../images/test_f03.jpg" alt="test_f03"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId3" title="test_f04"><img src="../images/test_f04.jpg" alt="test_f04"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId4" title="test_f05"><img src="../images/test_f05.jpg" alt="test_f05"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId5" title="test_f06"><img src="../images/test_f06.jpg" alt="test_f06"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId6" title="test_f07"><img src="../images/test_f07.jpg" alt="test_f07"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId7" title="test_f08"><img src="../images/test_f08.jpg" alt="test_f08"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId8" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId9" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/></a>
        <a href="#autoGeneratedId10" title="test_f09"><img src="../images/test_f09.jpg" alt="test_f09"/></a>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('|>[0-9]{1,2}<|','><',$html);
```